# Michael Hartl's gem file bundle install issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, gemfile

I am trying to install this gem file in Michael Hartl's tutorial using bundle install:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.26.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

and I run `bundle install` on my terminal.  I have this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
actionpack (= 4.2.4)

In Gemfile:
railties (>= 0) ruby depends on
  actionpack (= 4.2.4) ruby

web-console (>= 0) ruby depends on
  sprockets-rails (< 4.0, >= 2.0) ruby depends on
    actionpack (>= 3.0) ruby

rails (= 4.2.2) ruby depends on
  actionpack (= 4.2.2) ruby

actionpack (>= 0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Any clue for what is really going on here?  I tried bundle update and it is prompting me this: `An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that`gem install pg -v '0.17.1'`succeeds before bundling.`

Then if I install the pg, it still won't do it...

Comment: try just deleting the Gemfile.lock file and then bundle

Comment: do you have postgres running or installed? You can download the OS X client [here](http://postgresapp.com/)

Comment: Tried both deleting the Gemfile.lock and installing postgres.  Did not solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The production block in that tutorial is geared towards Heroku, you need to do the following:

```
bundle install --without production
```

As your local gemset doesn't need those Gems.

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning Rails you probably don't plan to push Michael Hartl's tutorial app to production. Just delete this block:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

This way the 'pg' gem is not needed. It's only if you want to use a postgresql server to run the app in production.

Then run bundle update and it should work just fine.

Comment: I think hartl does `bundle install --without production`. On a related note, any idea why if I do `rails new abcd`, I then change sqlite3 to pg 'cos heroku doesn't support sqlite3. I add a page that does nothing, 'cos I need a route e.g. root 'application#index' and I make a blank app/views/application/index.html.erb.  it works.   But If I comment out gem 'pg' then I get an error  Why would that be, if heroku doesn't need pg?

Comment: I notice https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5 says "If you’re using an existing app that was created without specifying --database=postgresql, you need to add the pg gem to your Rails project."      Would that suggest that hartl created his app with that --database=postgresql and thus he doesn't need a gem 'pg' line?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, install these two

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
bundle install
```

thats work for me